# how to create a popup onclick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

see below are what i tried.

jQuery:

```
$("#type_name").click(function(){
            $("#add_form").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#involved_name").val("");
            positionPopup('#add_form');
            $("#involved_name").focus();
        });
```

html:

```
<div id="add_form" style="display:none">
<h2>Enter involved Name<h2>
<table><tr><td>
<input type="text" id="involved_name" name="name" maxlength="20" /></td></tr>
</table>
<div style="width:180px;margin:20px 5px 0 10px" align="right">

            <button type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">
                <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/button-icon-ir-back.png" width="12" height="17" alt="" />
            Cancel</button>   {% include "buttons/add.html" %}
        </div>
</div>
```

onclick button on html:

```
<button type="submit" name="edit" class="forward" id="type_name"><font color="#026BE2">Type a name </font></button>
```

The above code is not working,not showing any errors in console,but popup is not displaying.Need help.

Comment: I don't see any problems here, works fine in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/a6tLh/ My guess would be you're assigning the click listener first and then rendering the button. Try it the opposite way.

Comment: For tooltips I used to use a plugin called [tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/index). I've tried a bunch of tooltip plugins and that one was the best. Most other tooltip plugins had limitations, but that one allowed me to do pretty much anything easily.

Comment: Try placing your code inside a `$.ready` perhaps

Comment: Alexander,i did the above,problem was solved,voted up

Comment: @MonkL, let me write it as an answer and then you can accept it to solve this matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't binding the event correctly after the DOM has been constructed. You may need to wrap your code around a `$.ready()`, or `$()` for short.

```
$(function () {
  $("#type_name").click(function () {
    $("#add_form").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#involved_name").val("");
    positionPopup('#add_form');
    $("#involved_name").focus();
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can simply move your piece of code just before the closing `body` tag i.e. `</body>`.

No other problems seems to be of much concern.

Answer (score -2):

Guess `$.ready` should work, as @Alexander has pointed out.
Also try `$("#type_name").live('click',function(){});` 
Incase of newer jQuery version replace `.live` by `.on`

This will bind your events dynamically... irrespective of your DOM loading.

Comment: No `.live()` please, before suggesting something as such a thing you should confirm first the jQuery version in use by commenting

Comment: I have given an suggestion and also have provided the .on() as an alternative for newer version of jQuery.
Please do let know if there's some fault in my reply.
For your information I actually gave you an UP VOTE before giving a reply.